# Gremlin Python createIndex (Tinkerpop)

Tags: python, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm currently using Tinkerpop with the [gremlin python client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gremlinpython/3.2.4) with the default [TinkerGraph-Gremlin](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#tinkergraph-gremlin)(which is running in-memory). I wanted to boost the performance of my queries and read about the `createIndex()` function which sounds like the perfect it for my use case, sadly I wasn't able to create an index with the python client. I also tried to add these lines into the start-up groovy script (run through the groovy scirpt without errors) but when I run my performance benchmarks I get the same results.

So my question is: Can I create an index with the python client and if not what would be a workaround? Also is there a way to ask gremlin if there are any indices defined?

PS.: For the groovy script I used the default `empty-sample.grooy` and add these lines before the last call:

```
graph.createIndex("name", Vertex.class)
graph.createIndex("nap", Edge.class)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Both approaches should work. out of curiosity, how large is your graph?

Comment: @stephenmallette the problem is that in the python client the createIndex() method is missing (as far as I can tell). And adding the two lines into the groovy script results in the same query times. About 8000 vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python client won't have a `createIndex()` method as TinkerPop does not provide any abstractions over indices in 3.x. We rely on the index and schema creation methods of the underlying graph database. You have to drop down to that API level and out of TinkerPop.

If you're only determining whether or not indices are created using the speed of your query keep in mind that your graph only has 8800 vertices in it and TinkerGraph is an in-memory graph. You might not see a massively discernible difference in speed with that few a number of vertices. If you want to know if your index is created just look it up:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> graph.createIndex('name',Vertex.class)
gremlin> graph.getIndexedKeys(Vertex.class)
==>name
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond! I checked the graph again: `g.V().count().next() 16000` and `g.E().count().next() 31000`. One last question: If I created an index on `name` I should always select `name` first with an `has('name', xxx)` statement?

Comment: With TinkerGraph you should put your most selective indexed property first. Other graphs may behave differently and do a better job optimizing a series of `has()` steps.

Answer (score 0):

Using gremlinpython v3.2.6

Searching the github of TinkerPop, I found you can send direct requests as it was the database console using the client object. This behaviour is explained in [the GitHub of Tinkerpop](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/docs/src/reference/gremlin-applications.asciidoc#connecting-via-python). I'll show the synchronous version, in the GitHub there's an asynchronous one also:

```
from gremlin_python.driver.client import Client

client = Client(url, travelsal_source)
console_command_string = "2*2"  # Write code as it was the console of the database you're using
result_set = client.submit(console_command_string)
future_results = result_set.all()
results = future_results.result()

client.close()
```

To see what command you have to send, look at the exact database you're using, in case of Janusgraph it is detailed in [its indexing documentation](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html).