# How to fix error: Script evaluation exceeded the configured 'scriptEvaluationTimeout' threshold of 30000

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

We have main API that connects to a Gremlin Server (EC2 Instance built from this [link](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend)). It's using DynamoDB to store data.

One query works but when we tried multiple queries simultaneously that's where the problem starts to appear. It's getting "**scriptEvaluationTimeout**".

The query goes something like this:
`g.V().has("users","email","user@example.com").inE().otherV().where(inE().otherV().has('users','email','user@example.com')).valueMap()`

Tried the following:

1. Upgraded EC2 instance from t2.micro to t2.medium. We found that the instance was running out of memory to run Java Runtime Environment so we upgraded.
2. Upgraded DynamoDB Capacity to Auto Scaling because it was exceeding the provisioned static capacity.
3. Tried updating the timeout to 60000 and tried updating other configurations but nothing worked.
4. Tried adding index but not sure if that was correct way to add index.

This is my first time to post question here and my first time to use Gremlin, JanusGraph. The dev who initially created this is no longer in connection and I'm seeking help through this platform. Has anyone experienced this? Please help. Thanks.

Update/Additional:

1. The query I posted above was just one of the query that gets the timeout issue. This one is more susceptible to that error.

```
WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.AbstractEvalOpProcessor  - Script evaluation exceeded the configured threshold for request [RequestMessage{, requestId=d60d8cf0-1b74-11ea-9299-d76eb09532d9, op='eval', processor='', args={gremlin=g.V().or(__.has('users','phone',within('+918329086936','112','18003001947')),__.has('users','email',within('user1@example.com','user2@yahoo.com','user3@example.com','user4@fastmail.com','user5@yahoo.com','user6@example.com','user7@gmail.com','user8@gmail.com','user9@gmail.com','user10@hotmail.com'))).not(has('users','email',within('dev@example.com','user5@yahoo.com','user1@example.com','user3@example.com','user9@gmail.com'))).not(has('users','email','dev@example.com')).order().by('name').valueMap(), bindings={}, accept=application/json, language=gremlin-groovy}}]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Script evaluation exceeded the configured 'scriptEvaluationTimeout' threshold of 30000 ms or evaluation was otherwise cancelled directly for request [g.V().or(__.has('users','phone',within('+918329086936','112','18003001947')),__.has('users','email',within('user1@example.com','user2@yahoo.com','user3@example.com','user4@fastmail.com','user5@yahoo.com','user6@example.com','user7@gmail.com','user8@gmail.com','user9@gmail.com','user10@hotmail.com'))).not(has('users','email',within('dev@example.com','user5@yahoo.com','user1@example.com','user3@example.com','user9@gmail.com'))).not(has('users','email','dev@example.com')).order().by('name').valueMap()]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$1(GremlinExecutor.java:337)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

2. I was also attempting to add index. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43678482/12799103) last week and was able to create index without error(s) and but didn't improve the query. I was also trying to add composite index using this reference from [JanusGraph documentation](https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-management/index-performance/#composite-index) but I was getting error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: groovysh_evaluate
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what is wrong exactly as there are many factors to consider. You mentioned that you added an index but didn't specify what kind of index. Given your traversal I think the most important one would be a composite index on the "email" property so that you get a fast initial lookup for the starting vertex (I assume that you expect a single starting vertex). I think you'd then want to make sure that this portion of the traversal is "fast":

```
g.V().has("users","email","user@example.com")
```

If it is not, then your index is not perhaps not setup right. After that you'd need to understand the structure of that your graph is traversing for:

```
g.V().has("users","email","user@example.com").
  inE().otherV().
  where(inE().otherV().has('users','email','user@example.com')).
  valueMap()
```

First note that you should typically avoid `otherV()` when you are sure of the traversal direction, thus:

```
g.V().has("users","email","user@example.com").
  in().
  where(__.in().has('users','email','user@example.com')).
  valueMap()
```

The question then becomes, how many paths are you analyzing with that traversal and is there opportunity to filter them down a bit (can you provide edge labels to `in()` or apply `has()` property filters to edges so that you can use vertex centric indices for example).

This is a fairly straightforward traversal otherwise, so unless traversing `in().in()` is forcing analysis of hundreds of thousands or millions of edges I wouldn't expect this to be a terribly time consuming query with the index discussed earlier in place. You might consider giving Gremlin Server a more memory if you have not done so already - you can see the `-Xmx` setting in `gremlin-server.sh` (or perhaps `janusgraph.sh` in your case).

Aside from that, I can't think of much else you might try. I'm not sure if the DynamoDB backend to JanusGraph is the most popular. You might try asking more about it on the [JanusGraph User Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/janusgraph-users) to see what folks think about it.

Comment: Thanks for answering @stephenmallette. The query I posted above was just one of the queries that gets the timeout issue. I have a query that is more susceptible to that error. I'll post the logs somewhere here (characters are too long for this comment section).

Comment: I've updated my question above and added some more details and errors from the logs. thanks.

Comment: based on your additional information, i assume that you don't have an index created. that answer you linked to is for TinkerGraph, not JanusGraph so I'm not sure what effect it would have. you should be creating your index as described in you link to the JanusGraph documentation. the error you are getting means that the "graph" as a variable name has not been configured in Gremlin Server properly - perhaps you have it named as something else.

Comment: the traversal you say is more susceptible for timeouts could be just a problem with a missing index but i'd also wonder how JanusGraph optimizes that query. it could be that even if you created the index successfully JanusGraph would fail to properly resolve the conditions you have there to use it given the complexity there. I'd `explain()` and `profile()` the traversal to see how it is being compiled/executed.

Comment: finally, i assume that you are not submitting these request though Gremlin Console and that you are using a driver to submit scripts to Gremlin Server. If so it does not appear that you are parameterizing those scripts. please using bytecode based traversals or at least parameterize your scripts: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#parameterized-scripts that will make a very large impact on resources usage and performance.

Comment: thanks a lot for your recommendations. I'm trying to apply these. Kinda stuck with indexing. I was able to create composite indexes but the status is still INSTALLED. I can't turn it to REGISTERED before re-indexing. I'm searching for solution to this problem. If you have idea on this, please let me know. thank you again :)

Tried to remove open transactions and increase the timeout of awaitGraphIndexStatus but nothing worked. 

`mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'byEmailComposite').timeout(10, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES).call()`